# Why doesn't Pakistan establish a diplomatic relationship with Israel?

Tags: israel, pakistan

At least 10 Muslim countries recognize Israel.

1. Turkey (1949)
2. Egypt (1979)
3. Albania (1991)
4. Azerbaijan (1992)
5. Kazakhstan (1992)
6. Kyrgyzstan (1992)
7. Uzbekistan (1992)
8. Tajikistan (1992)
9. Turkmenistan (1992)
10. Jordan (1994)

Then, why doesn't Pakistan maintain a diplomatic relationship with Israel?

Is there any disadvantage for Pakistan in establishing a full-fledged diplomatic relationship with Israel?

Comment: Giving cash generally works as far as being helped economically :)

Comment: What do you mean by "should"? You are going to have to clarify your question, or it is too opinion based.

Comment: #11:  The Maldives.

Comment: I think there is more. For instance, Bosnia&Herzegovina, Senegal... Also, I think Albania recognized Israel much earlier, this date maybe for diplomatic relations.

Comment: @Anixx, Bosnia is not a Muslim country.

Comment: @anonymous, what is ‘Muslim country’ then? If you refer to the state religion, then none of your examples besides Jordan are relevant.  Moreover, I could not see much sense in referring to formerly Socialistic countries (most of your list from Albania to Turkmenia) as ‘Muslim’ on a par with Jordan and countries that does not recognize Israel (i. e. Saudi Arabia, Libya, etc), even if most of their population considering themselves Muslim.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov, A Muslim country is the one which is both Muslim-majority and ruled by Muslims.

Comment: @anonymous That seems to be some pan-Islamic definition. Let's see for example, when Kingdom of Hungary was ruled by Austria, did it cease to be a Hungarian country as it was no longer ruled by Hungarians despite having a Hungarian majority? Or when Marshall Bernadotte took Swedish throne, Sweden became French instead of Swedish? Or when Julia Gillard, an atheist, became Prime Minister of Australia, it ceased to be a Christian majority country?

Comment: @nsnoob, all of them are Yes.

Comment: @nsnoob, in this case, pan-islamic definition is the appropriate one. Otherwise, India will also claim that the are Muslim country.

Comment: @anonymous Huh? Since when is India a Muslim majority country? Having a sizeable Muslim population doesn't mean a Muslim majority.

Comment: @nsnoob, see for yourself. https://thewire.in/10563/india-more-islamic-than-pakistan-rajnath-says-in-meeting-with-pakistan-rangers/

Comment: Albania is not a Muslim country ..

Answer (score 10):

The hatred toward Israel has more to do with Islamization rather than real disputes (which simply don't exist). The Pakistanis feel that the Ummah needs their help. This is due to the rising influence of Arab culture on the psyche of Pakistanis. To distance themselves from India, they are trying to get close to Arabia (the Saudis in particular). This Arab influence can be seen in the changing language (Ramadan instead of Ramazan, Allah Hafiz vs Khuda Hafiz) and the TV shows like Shaheen (which deal with the Reconquista). Their growing obsession with Arab culture naturally grates with Zionism. The establishment has been trying to foster a psuedo-arab identity onto modern-day Pakistanis.

Answer (score 1):

Because Pakistan is a *jihadi* state.

Why would you expect a country that:

- sponsored the Taliban in Afghanistan,
- rescued Osama bin Laden,
- provided a base for Osama bin Laden,
- allows training camps in its territory for *jihadi* guerrilla wars in two of its neighbors?  (Afghanistan and India)
- sponsored a terror raid against the Indian parliament, and
- sponsored a terror raid against Bombay's financial district

to want to seem to endorse the Zionist government that controls Jerusalem?

By the way, at most two of the countries in that list (Jordan and maybe Egypt) were ruled by *de facto* Muslims when they recognized Israel.  Turkey was ruled by a faction that actively suppressed both Christian and Muslim religiosity in politics.  Albania, Azerbaijan, and the five Central Asian former Soviet Socialist Republics were ruled by people who were as much former Communists (*de facto* atheists) as Muslims.

Comment: This is a rant.

Comment: Also, Egypt only did so because they were first beaten to a pulp by Israel in 1973 and then pushed (or even bought via aid) by USA to establish relationship.

Comment: And Jordan is ruled by a "foreign" dynasty that is in precarious relationship with the populace, and needs Western support.

Answer (score -1):

Pakistan has refused to recognize Israel. Pakistani cannot visit Israel.
passports bear the inscription `"This passport is valid for all countries of the World except Israel.`

Under Israeli law, Pakistan is a designated "enemy state" and an Israeli citizen may not visit them without a special permit issued by the Israeli Interior Ministry

Comment: The question asked "WHY" that is

Comment: "This passport is valid for all countries of the World except Israel" - does not this inscription actually mean recognition? I think they do not write something like "valid for all countries except ISIS" if they don't recognize ISIS.